# Error while navigating from edit/id to home and other pages. Navingation stucks at edit/id and changes to edit/add or edit/home instead of resto/home

Tags: php, laravel, post, navigation

Error while navigating from edit/id to home and other pages. Navingation stucks at edit/id and changes to edit/add or edit/home instead of resto/home . Also while hiting update getting error POST method is not supported 
This is my route-web code

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('home','RestoController@index');
Route::get('list','RestoController@list');
Route::post('add','RestoController@add');
Route::view('add','add');
Route::get('delete/{id}','RestoController@delete');
Route::get('edit/{id}','RestoController@edit');
```

This is my edit code

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1>Edit Restaurant</h1>
<form action="edit" method="post">
@csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$data->id}}">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{$data->name}}" placeholder="Enter Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{$data->email}}" placeholder="Enter Email ID">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="{{$data->address}}" placeholder="Enter Address">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

</div>

@stop
```

and This is my Controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Restaurant;
use Session;

class RestoController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function list()
    {
        $data= Restaurant::all();
        return view('list',["data"=>$data]);
    }

    function add(Request $req)
    {
        // return $req->input();
        $resto = new Restaurant;

        $resto->name=$req->input('name');
        $resto->email=$req->input('email');
        $resto->address=$req->input('address');
        $resto->save();
        $req->session()->flash('status','Restaurant added successfully');
        return redirect('list');

    }

    function delete($id, Request $req)
    {
        Restaurant::find($id)->delete();
        Session::flash('status','Restaurant deleted successfully');
        return redirect('list');

    }

    function edit($id)
    {
        $data= Restaurant::find($id);
        return view('edit',["data"=>$data]);
    }

    function update(Request $req)
    {

        $resto = Restaurant::find($req->input('id'));
        $resto->name=$req->input('name');
        $resto->email=$req->input('email');
        $resto->address=$req->input('address');
        $resto->save();
        $req->session()->flash('status','Restaurant updated successfully');
        return redirect('list');

    }

}
```

please help me and guide me where i am lacking ? also, while hitting update got error - the POST method is not supported, Thanks

Comment: You don't have post route for update in your routes.

Comment: Rikesh Sir, i have added post route in routes but still getting same error, please help me. Thanks